# GDB reads debug symbols locally but not in cloud

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb

I have a suite of programs that I developed locally, and I have uploaded the files to a cloud server at Digital Ocean -- a procedure I have done many times before.  However, this is a new cloud server and I am having a problem I have never had before:  GDB reads debug symbols locally but not in cloud, so in the cloud I can't see the source code lines as I debug.  The programs compile the same way both locally and cloud.

The program starts with a C wrapper whose purpose is to call a shared object written in NASM.  Several other C object files are linked into the NASM shared object.  All files are compiled with -g or -ggdb.  I have used this same setup many times for about 5 years.

The cloud server is running NASM 2.15.05; locally it's running 2.14.02.  GDB locally is 9.2; in the cloud it's "GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1."  GCC locally is 9.4.0; in the cloud it's 11.4.0.  Locally I run Ubuntu 20.04 and in the cloud it's 22.04.

On startup, I set a breakpoint in the NASM file.  In the cloud, GDB steps through each instruction, but does not show source code for each line.  Initially I thought the problem was the source file location because info source says:

```
(gdb) info source
No current source file.
```

But it's in $cwd in both places.  Locally info source shows the correct file.

Then I looked at debug symbols.  Everything was compiled with -ggdb except NASM, which is
assembled with -g ("nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf Calc_XYZ.asm").  When I do GDB's "info sources" command locally, I get a full read of all files for which sources have been or will be read.  In the cloud, all programs and object files show as "Full debug information has not yet been read for this file", e.g.:

```
(gdb) info sources
/opt/P01_SH/_Debug_Wrappers_in_C/Call_Create_Threads_in_C-Calc.exe:
(Full debug information has not yet been read for this file.)
```

When I do "objdump --syms Calc_XYZ.so | grep debug" in the cloud I get nothing, but locally it's:

```
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_aranges 0000000000000000              .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_pubnames    0000000000000000              .debug_pubnames
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_info    0000000000000000              .debug_info
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_abbrev  0000000000000000              .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_line    0000000000000000              .debug_line
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_frame   0000000000000000              .debug_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_loc 0000000000000000              .debug_lo
```

But there ARE debug symbols in the file.  I run the Linux "file" command in the cloud:

```
$ file Create_Threads_in_C-Calc_XYZ.o
Create_Threads_in_C-Calc_XYZ.o: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=e230e001a6e0b4ae9dadafa66c0b26edcaf87317, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Okay, with debug_info and not stripped.  I get the same response for all the other files.

Next I tried `objdump -g Calc_XYZ.so` and I got a lot of debug info:

```
Calc_XYZ.so:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of the .eh_frame section (loaded from Calc_XYZ.so):

Contents of the .debug_aranges section (loaded from Calc_XYZ.so):

  Length:                   44
  Version:                  2
  Offset into .debug_info:  0x0
  Pointer Size:             8
  Segment Size:             0

    Address            Length
    0000000000001000 00000000000008b4 
    0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Contents of the .debug_info section (loaded from Calc_XYZ.so):

  Compilation Unit @ offset 0x0:
   Length:        0x51 (32-bit)
   Version:       3
   Abbrev Offset: 0x0
   Pointer Size:  8
 <0><b>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
    <c>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x1000
    <14>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x1000
    <1c>   DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x0
    <20>   DW_AT_name        : Calc_XYZ.asm
    <34>   DW_AT_producer    : NASM 2.15.05
    <41>   DW_AT_language    : 32769    (MIPS assembler)
 <1><43>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <44>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x1000
    <4c>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 0x0 (location list)
 <1><50>: Abbrev Number: 0

Contents of the .debug_abbrev section (loaded from Calc_XYZ.so):

  Number TAG (0x0)
   1      DW_TAG_compile_unit    [has children]
    DW_AT_low_pc       DW_FORM_addr
    DW_AT_high_pc      DW_FORM_addr
    DW_AT_stmt_list    DW_FORM_data4
    DW_AT_name         DW_FORM_string
    DW_AT_producer     DW_FORM_string
    DW_AT_language     DW_FORM_data2
    DW_AT value: 0     DW_FORM value: 0
   2      DW_TAG_subprogram    [no children]
    DW_AT_low_pc       DW_FORM_addr
    DW_AT_frame_base   DW_FORM_data4
    DW_AT value: 0     DW_FORM value: 0

Raw dump of debug contents of section .debug_line (loaded from Calc_XYZ.so):

  Offset:                      0x0
  Length:                      943
  DWARF Version:               3
  Prologue Length:             374
  Minimum Instruction Length:  1
  Initial value of 'is_stmt':  1
  Line Base:                   -5
  Line Range:                  14
  Opcode Base:                 13

 Opcodes:
  Opcode 1 has 0 args
  Opcode 2 has 1 arg
  Opcode 3 has 1 arg
  Opcode 4 has 1 arg
  Opcode 5 has 1 arg
  Opcode 6 has 0 args
  Opcode 7 has 0 args
  Opcode 8 has 0 args
  Opcode 9 has 1 arg
  Opcode 10 has 0 args
  Opcode 11 has 0 args
  Opcode 12 has 1 arg

 The Directory Table is empty.

 The File Name Table (offset 0x1c):
  Entry Dir     Time    Size    Name
  1     0       0       0       Calc_XYZ.asm
  2     0       0       0       /opt/P01_SH/_Include_Utilities/Virtual_Memory_Multi.asm
  3     0       0       0       /opt/P01_SH/_Include_Utilities/Init_Cores.asm
  4     0       0       0       /opt/P01_SH/_Include_Utilities/Registers_Push_NoAVX.asm
  5     0       0       0       /opt/P01_SH/_Include_Utilities/Stack_Align_In.asm
  6     0       0       0       /opt/P01_SH/_Include_Utilities/Stack_Align_Out.asm
  7     0       0       0       /opt/P01_SH/_Include_Utilities/Registers_Pop_NoAVX.asm

 Line Number Statements:
  [0x00000180]  Extended opcode 2: set Address to 0x1000
  [0x0000018b]  Advance Line by 81 to 82
  [0x0000018e]  Copy
  [0x0000018f]  Special opcode 20: advance Address by 1 to 0x1001 and Line by 1 to 83
  [0x00000190]  Special opcode 20: advance Address by 1 to 0x1002 and Line by 1 to 84
  Special opcodes go on for many pages.   I removed them from here to save space.
```

Finally, I ran `nm -uD /opt/P01_SH/_Debug_Wrappers_in_C/Call_Create_Threads_in_C-Calc.exe` and it shows its symbols:

```
                 U create_file_mmap
                 U create_mmap
                 U End_Clock
                 U ___error
                 U fclose
                 U fopen
                 U fread
                 U fseek
                 U fseeko
                 U ftell
                 U ftello
                 U fwrite
                 U get_core_count_C
                 U grow_mmap
                 U mmap
                 U munmap
                 U Print_Time
                 U query_avail_memory
                 U sched_getcpu
                 U Start_Clock
                 U thread_create_in_C
```

And in the cloud:
`nm -uD /opt/P01_SH/_Debug_Wrappers_in_C/Call_Create_Threads_in_C-Calc.exe`

```
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w __gmon_start__
                 U __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.34
                 U clock@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U dlerror@GLIBC_2.34
                 U dlopen@GLIBC_2.34
                 U dlsym@GLIBC_2.34
                 U exit@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U fprintf@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U printf@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U puts@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U stderr@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

So my question is:  why does GDB read the source debug symbols locally for the shared object and all of its linked-in object files, but not in the cloud, even when there are debug symbols in the files?  Why does GDB skip reading them?

Comment: I notice in one place you use `info source` and in the other `info sources`.  These are two different commands.  The first tells you about the current source file -- only valid if the inferior is currently stopped within the executable (i.e. there is a program counter value to map back to a single source file), the second command `info sources` lists all source files for all objfiles in the current inferior.

Comment: Rather than using `--syms` to check for debug, you're better off doing `objdump -h OBJECT | grep debug` which will tell you what debug sections are present.  But given the `file` output, I suspect this will just show the same sections are present in both locations.

Comment: It would be more helpful if we say the whole GDB session, rather than just a single command in isolation.  I'm wondering, have you started the executable?  If you have, when GDB stopped, did it list the source file/line correctly?  Seeing a complete GDB session would help with these questions.

Comment: @Andrew - yes, the executable was started.  No, when GDB stopped it did not list the source file and line.